# How to use Subtotal in a Filter Data with ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, subtotal

I've created a simple table and trying to sequence datas with Subtotal (CountA) in my Filter Datas.

[Datas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXN16.png)

A: Subtotal with ArrayFormula

B: Subtotal without ArrayFormula

Here is my exp:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SOiu0YHFLZB50d7h7gWQeobxKBto_n3llm-Ej1MazWU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What would be your desired output?

Comment: Its sequence data, but count from 1 to datas number when I filter datas

Comment: See my answer. See your sheet `F Column`.

Comment: Glad to know! If it helps then please accept the answer (tick mark it) to threat the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MAP()` then `SUBTOTAL()` inside it.

```
=MAP(E2:INDEX(E2:E,COUNTA(E2:E)),LAMBDA(x,SUBTOTAL(3,E2:INDEX(E2:E,ROW(x)-1))))
```

[image]

Comment: [Sample File link here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UASuvmQRbgXZ3l8P48E1V9JO6yOVDKhcSch3dW_qhzU/edit#gid=754583768)